# Puppeteer launch not working for no specific reason

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, puppeteer, nestjs

Puppeteer launch not working for no specific reason. I'm completely confused because the same code works fine on basic node.js app. Even tho this is nest.js which i started learning this week, i'm still unable to find any workaround and solutions.
Tried with headless true & false and also with -> args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'].
If anyone had similar experience, please tell. :/

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jifi7.png)

Comment: Please don't attach screenshots of the code. It's hard for people to copy and replicate the code. Share your code in the question's description as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing it the wrong way.
Hence it gives you the type error,
`Cannot read property "launch" of undefined`
as puppeteer is `undefined` as you imported it in the wrong manner.

This should fix it,

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much :D
Have a great weekend

Comment: I clicked an upvote instantly, but don't know how to mark it as accepted ?
@Ramaraja Ramanujan

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Oh my god i'm literally blind ...
Done :D
@Ramaraja Ramanujan